# Principle argument. Conway's problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be meromorphic on the region $G$ and not constant; show that neither the poles nor the zeros of $f$ have a limit point  $G$.

How solve this question?

Comment: This is a standard theorem in basic complex analysis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: Thanks! I did not remember this theorem.